# Best practice for storing private key in server

Tags: keys

We are an exchange and user may deposit tokens in our EOS exchange account and do transaction later. We need to store our exchange account's private key in server securely. What is the best practice to store the private key?
The program in the server need to use the private key to sign message(using eosjs).