# What are recommended best practices for block producer key management?

Tags: block-producer

I am not aware of BP key management best practices if there are any would be helpful.

I see these 2 questions:

[Is It safe to Store User keys on local db server?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2165/is-it-safe-to-store-user-keys-on-local-db-server)
[Best practice for storing private key in server](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/best-practice-for-storing-private-key-in-server)

But neither really addresses best practices for a block producer storing their key.

I'm also curious if you can just linkauth the eosio:onblock action to minimize the risk if the key is compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some thoughts from people that have hands on experience

https://t.me/c/1252343263/66216

[image]